# Are there connection-less ORM frameworks?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, ado.net

I have an ADO.NET disconnected DataSet. I don't need or can use an ADO.NET connection, transaction, command or anything besides that DataSet and its content. That is a non-optional limitation of the persistence library I have to use.

Are there any ORM frameworks that can do all the mapping stuff without connecting to the database?

Comment: I've never used it, but I guess Linq to DataSet may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387004.aspx. However you still need to do your mapping manually.

Comment: It is so sad, every answer and comment given would be acceptable if I could connect directly with ADO.NET. Unfortunately I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a library that does just that:

http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Not specific for DataSet's, but can be easily used with them:

http://house9.blogspot.com/2010/11/automapper-datatable-to-list.html

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your dataset to a [Typed DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and then use [linq-to-dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) to query it.

EDIT : Untested but you could maybe use [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/MappingDataSetToXMLAndBackwards.aspx) to translate the schema of your dataset to xml and then use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wha85tzb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#Y564) to translate it to a typed dataset class.

Comment: Creating a Typed DS is probably not an option, but maybe it is Typed.

Comment: But (s)he could load the data of his dataset into the typed dataset by using [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.merge(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataSet.WriteXmlSchema() to create a XSD file describing your DataSet, and then execute (in Microsoft SDKs folder) xsd.exe /c yourschema.xsd destinationfolder

You will obtain classes with the structure of your DataSet... It can't do all the mapping work for you, but you'll probably find a way to do this quickly when you'll have the classes generated.

Hope it helps.

Edit : Using this kind of code, maybe : http://improve.dk/blog/2007/11/19/automatically-mapping-datatable-to-objects

Comment: I like that function. But it is way too minimalist, it does not handle lists for example. I would love to find out someone built a library for this sort of tasks, otherwise I will end up coding it myself.